# {=Table(,B8)} Formula?

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a spreadsheet that has a cell with `{=Table(,B8)}` but I cant see the formula that is generating the values..Basically I want to see how the values in this table is being calculated (by viewing the underlying formula). How can I do this?

Comment: The `=TABLE()` formulas are results of an Excel's  `Data - What-If Analysis - Data Table`. See http://www.excel-easy.com/examples/data-tables.html and http://www.techrepublic.com/blog/windows-and-office/create-an-excel-data-table-to-compare-multiple-results/ and more results in web research using keywords `excel data table what if analysis`

Comment: Thank you, I appreciate it!